# bootstrap 3 - fixed side bar to full column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns (`col-md-8` and `col-md-4`). The second column contains a fixed side bar. I want the side bar to be 100% width of the `col-md-4` column. The black box as seen in the image below is the second column.

I have tried width 100% but it does not work.

[image]

Here's my HTML.

```css
.col-md-4 {
  border-style: solid;
}
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
.well {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed affix">
        <div class="well" id="world">
          <ul class="nav ">
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.well -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
</div>
```

Comment: Provide your code, if possible, add working snippet.

Comment: Please add relevant css too.

Comment: Please see post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:fixed` element is supposed to define everything (including width) in relation to the viewport.

The only way in css to set width according to it's parent div is `width:inherit`

or if jquery is allowed you can use following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var new_width = $('.col-md-4').width();
  $('.sidebar-nav-fixed').width(new_width);
})
$(window).resize(function(){
  var new_width = $('.col-md-4').width();
  $('.sidebar-nav-fixed').width(new_width);
})
```

```css
.col-md-4 {
  border-style: solid;
}
.sidebar-nav-fixed {
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
.well {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="sidebar-nav-fixed affix">
        <div class="well" id="world">
          <ul class="nav ">
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!--/.well -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--/row-->
</div>
```